# SetRate(0.5) not working

Tags: c#, winapi, directshow, directshow.net

I am trying to set the rate of playback in directshow and all the filter say it can set it and when I do, then get the rate, it appears to be applied but the rate of playback does not reflect this change and I'm unsure why.

```
rate = 0.5;
mediaSeek.SetRate(rate);
mediaSeek.GetRate(out rate);
// rate = 0.5.
```

I've done this in another graph that I connected filters manually and it worked perfectly but this time I set the graph up as so:

```
filterGraph = graph as IFilterGraph2;

if (filterGraph != null)
{
    IBaseFilter sourceFilter;
    filterGraph.AddSourceFilter(source, source, out sourceFilter);

    IEnumPins pinEnum;
    sourceFilter.EnumPins(out pinEnum);

    var fetched = IntPtr.Zero;
    IPin[] pins = { null };

    while (pinEnum.Next(pins.Length, pins, fetched) == 0)
    {
        filterGraph.RenderEx(pins[0], AMRenderExFlags.RenderToExistingRenderers, IntPtr.Zero);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pins[0]);
    }

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pinEnum);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sourceFilter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SetRate` as well as other individual aspects of positioning and `IMediaSeeking`/`IMediaPosition` capabilities depends on how filter graph and individual filters handle the processing all together.

Filter graph manager accepts your requests and distributes between filters participating in the graph, doing it in specific way: rednerers are taking the requests from the filter graph manager, and then they are responsible to forward that upstream through other filters. Basically, any filter in the graph, which is processing the requests incorrectly might break the whole thing.

So your symptom is highly dependent on the filters participating in your graph. It is likely that one or several applies:

- some filters are not forwarding that properly
- demultiplexer filter is handling rate change incorrectly
- processing strips timestamps making it unable to schedule payload presentation in a proper way